# wildcard parameters in @angular/router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using @angular/router @ version 2.0.0-rc.1

I can't seem to get wildcard parameters working, and from reading the code it seems there is no support.

- Am I correct in that rc.1 router doesn't support wildcard params?
- Will this feature be re-added? (I saw no mention of wildcard params in https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WLSNV3V1AKdwLwRiLuN7JqbPBKQ_S5quRlcT5LPIldw/edit#heading=h.blfh5ya9sf5r, the design doc linked to from the angular changelog)
- Anyone have a sneaky workaround?

Comment: It will be added with one of the next versions.

Comment: Cool, will continue with @angular2/router-deprecated for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Angular 2.0.0 (final release) and the new router you can normally use wildcards, now paths are being used without slash.

NOTE:
the order of the routes matters: it should go from the most specific to the least specific. So as for the simple example below, the route '**' (matches anything) should be put at the end, so all the other possible routes would be covered by the previous ones.

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {   
 { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
 { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
 { path: '**', component: LoginComponent },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this in app.ts

```
import {Home} from './Home';

...

@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/home', component: Home, name: 'Home' },
  { path: '/**', redirectTo: ['Home'] }
])
```

In this example,we only have one real route set up, and that is the /home route. We are also instructing the app to redirect any request to unrecognized routes to the Home component. Each RouteDefinition requires a path, a name, and either a component, loader, or redirectTo.

Comment: this example is using the old router though, right? (You have @RouteConfig, plus I see no handling of ** specifically in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/router/src/recognize.ts)

Comment: This is Angular2. You can read about it on this blog. https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/25/angular-2-series-part-4-component-router-in-depth/

Comment: Angular2 also has an old router ;-). With RC.0 a new router was introduced. The old router is available as `router-deprecated`. Your example clearly uses `router-deprecated` because in the new router there is no `name` argument anymore.